# How to connect from BitBucket via ssh to a server?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

**What I want to achieve** is to connect from BitBucket to my server to deploy my application using BitBucket pipeline. For this I need to trigger a shell script on the server. I found many tutorials how to do it the other way round - from my server to BitBucket (to do git push, for example). That is working fine, using the SSH keys.
My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file looks like this:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo "I made a pipeline!"
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          script:
            - ssh -T userid@myserver.hostingcompany.sk -p12345 'cd /home/website.com/sub/pb; ./pull_dev.sh'
```

However, when I run it it fails with this error:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

I read someshere that I needed to add an access key. BitBucket did not allow me to add the one I am using as an SSH key for connecting **to** BitBucket, so I generated a new one, added it to the ss agent and to access keys settings on BitBucket. I also tried to put bitbucket.org into the list of known servers on my server but this did not help either.

I am now out of ideas so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just covering all the bases: did you add an SSH key in Pipelines, or create one there, and then add the corresponding public key to your target server?

Comment: How do I add an SSH key in Pipelines? I created one on server and then add it in the Access keys.

Comment: The repo's Access keys screen is for adding public SSH keys that third-party systems (like a CI/CD system) can use to connect automatically. Pipelines has its own screen where you can give it private SSH keys; it's called "SSH keys" and it's in the admin panel under "Pipelines".

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/access-remote-hosts-via-ssh-847452940.html